# Action Button in Angular UI Grid 3.x version

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to render a simple table using [Angular UI Grid (unstable version)](http://ui-grid.info/).
Against each row I need a button when clicked should be handled in my parent controller.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KuptJG?p=preview)

Javascript:-

```
angular.module("app", ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.expandable', 'ui.grid.paging']).controller("appController", function($scope) {
  console.log("Controller is up.");
  $scope.data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    $scope.data.push({
      fullName: "Name" + i,
      age: i
    });
  }

  $scope.clickHandler = function(){
    // this never gets invoked ?!
    console.log("Row Action click Handler.");
  };


  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: $scope.data,
    columnDefs:[ {name:'fullName',field:'fullName'},
              {name:'age',field:'age'},
              {name:' ',cellTemplate:'<div><button ng-click="clickHandler()">Click Here</button></div>'}
            ]
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="app">
  <h1>Angular UI Grid unstable</h1>
  <div data-ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions">
      Test 
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As in code, to render the action button I have used **columnDefs** with inline template for the third column.

### PROBLEM

Clicking the button doesn't work. I expect ' **$scope.clickHandler**' function to be executed on click. Also, I should be able to pass 'name' as argument to the click handler.

Comment: Here's a plunker with similar usage and it seems to fire ng-click inside clickhandler: http://plnkr.co/edit/BZKiZoevJQ1YgR0w7yy6?p=preview

Comment: @trainoasis; Your plunker seems to be working fine.But, 1) You are using ng-grid (the older version of UI Grid) 2) What is wrong in mine ?

Comment: This plunker is not mine, just found it while searching for your solution. I can't see anything really wrong with yours at the moment, I suggest you go side-by-side with the working one and perhaps find your issue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the new `ui-grid` everything happens in an `isolated` scope. So they added functionality to handle `external` scopes.

Here is what to do:

In the html define you grid like this:

```
<div class="grid" external-scopes="clickHandler" ui-grid="gridOptions">
```

Also add the external scope object (with a callable function) to your controller:

```
 $scope.clickHandler = {
     onClick : function(value){
        alert('Name: '+value);
     }
 };
```

Finally define your cellTemplate like this:

```
{
    name:'Action',
    cellTemplate: '<div><button ng-click="getExternalScopes().onClick(row.entity.fullName)">Click Here</button></div>'
}
```

Here is your forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8x5pBg3eR6yBHsQcGBDp?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Where can I read about this new 'isolated' scope approach?

Comment: FYI, you can use grid.appScope with appScopeProvider instead of external-scopes

Answer (score 41):

Easier than @mainguy in my opinion is:

Adding `grid.appScope.` before your $scope member.
For example in your case to call `$scope.clickHandler`:

```
cellTemplate:'<button ng-click="grid.appScope.clickHandler()">Click Here</button>'
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @gdoron's answer but for `controllerAs` syntax. In your controller, you should set `appScopeProvider` option to point to `this` object:

```
this.gridOptions = {
  ...,
  appScopeProvider: this
};
```

Then, `cellTemplate:'<button ng-click="grid.appScope.clickHandler()">Click Here</button>'`

**FYI**: by default, the parent scope of the ui-grid element will be assigned to grid.appScope this property allows you to assign any reference you want to grid.appScope

Comment: You can also do `grid.appScope.{controllerAs variable here}.clickHandler()` so if your controllerAs variable was 'm', you could do `grid.appScope.m.clickHandler()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have notice, if you are using routing config instead of assigning the app-controller directly, getExternalScopes() method works as expected with one note

in the respective controller, assign the below statement 
  $scope.gridScope = $scope;